# The probability that $x^2 \neq 1 \pmod p$ is not independent to the same thing modulo another odd prime $q$. What?! 

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, independence

Let $p,q$ be odd primes.

Clearly, the probability that $x \in \Bbb{Z}$ chosen at random is such that $x^2 \neq 1 \pmod p$ for a prime is $\frac{p - 2}{p}$ because there are precisely the two solutions $x \neq p \pm 1 \pmod p$, and these repeat with cyclicity of length $p$.

But, for the $pq$ case the answer is clearly $\frac{pq - 4}{pq}$ since $|G_{pq}| = \{ x \in \Bbb{Z}/pq : x^2 = 1 \pmod {pq}\}| = 2^{\omega(pq)} = 2^2 = 4$.  Of course, $pq - |G_{pq}| = pq - 4$ reresents the measurement in the title.

Thus, the probability that $x^2 \neq 1\pmod p$ and $x^2 \neq 1 \pmod q$ cannot be handled using basic multiplication (it's for independent events only by definition).

Since the probability for the $pq$ case via CRT *is* the same thing as the $p$ AND'd with the $q$ case, we have that:

$$
\text{Pr}[x^2 \neq 1\pmod p] \text{Pr}[x^2 \neq 1 \pmod q] \\ \ \\ = \frac{p-2}{p} \frac{q - 2}{q} \\ \ \\ = \frac{pq - 2p - 2q + 4}{pq} =^{?} \frac{pq - 4}{pq}
$$

Equating results in:

$$
4 - 2p - 2q = -4 \\
8 = 2p + 2q
$$

There exist no odd primes such that the above holds.  Therefore solving $x^2 - 1 \neq 0$ modulo $q$ is not independent of the same thing modulo $p$ whenever $p \neq q$ are odd primes.

Do I have this right?

I honestly thought they would be independent.

Comment: You write $\frac{p-2}p$ (etc.) when I believe you mean $\frac2p$ (etc.). The correct quantities will confirm independence.

Comment: @GregMartin Woops, I got it backwards, let me edit, but I don't mean $2/p$

Comment: There is n9 uniform random variable on $\mathbb Z.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews how do I express then over a finite length $[0, n]$ as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The flaw in the argument is that $x^2\not\equiv1\pmod{pq}$ is CRT-equivalent to $x^2\not\equiv1\pmod{p}$ **OR** $x^2\not\equiv1\pmod{q}$, rather than "and".

Comment: What's interesting is I then did the union assuming independent events (inclusion-exclusion formula for counting OR'd sets), and the formulas equate!  It's freakin amazing.